# Finding a bound on ground state energy derivatives of molecule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

Part of a project I'm working on involves exploring the smoothness of the ground state energy $E(x)$ of a molecule where $E$ is parameterized by  the geometry of the molecule. In particular, my goal is to find some $f(k, x)$ where $\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i_1}}\dots\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i_k}}E(x)\right|\le f(k, x)$ if possible.

I'm not sure where to begin attacking this problem. My current knowledge is quite shallow (it stops at knowing there are analytic formulas for these derivatives). I'd be extremely grateful if someone could point me to somewhere as a starting point.

Cheers.

Comment: Perhaps the [Hellmann-Feynman theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellmann%E2%80%93Feynman_theorem) could be of use...?